# git shows random files changed on Mac NFS filesystem

Tags: linux, git, osx-snow-leopard, nfs

We have a strange problem here at work that I've been unable to figure out.  We all use MacBooks with Snow Leopard on our desktops and we have a handful of Linux servers we also use remotely.  Some of my team members put git repositories on an NFS filesystem that's shared between both the Mac's and the Linux servers so they don't have to think about sharing code between repositories in their personal workflow.

This is where the strange starts, on the OSX machines git will randomly show some files out of date <s>in status</s> when you try to merge or switch branches etc.  If you run `git status` no files are shown out of date. `gitk` will show the files as modified but not committed in the same way status normally does. If you `reset --hard` those files you can *sometimes* change branches before this reoccurs but mostly not.  If you log into one of the Linux machines and view the same repository everything works perfectly.  The files are not marked as changed and you can do whatever you like.

I've eliminated Line ending differences and file mode differences as the culprit but I'm not sure what else to try.  Is there some OSX specific NFS interaction that we have to work around somehow?

Comment: Does your NFS server preserve the executable bit properly?

Comment: addition to @Romains question: when the files are shown 'out of date': what does `git diff` return?

Comment: I've updated my post a bit, I was mistaken the files do not actually show up in status.  `git diff` shows nothing (returns immediately with no output).  `ls -l` on both Mac and Linux look the same, is there something else I should be looking at?  In emacs with whitespace mode enabled the files appear to be the same on both Linux and Mac and have the same file encoding.

Comment: What are the affected filenames?  As a wild guess based on insufficient information, you have files whose names differ only in letter case.

Comment: Nope, all filenames are completely different.  The reason there's not more information is that this is all I really know.  I've been trying to figure this out off and on for a while now and I've tried everything I've been able to find online.  It's not even consistently the same files, just some random set of 10+ files in a project with several hundred files in it.

Comment: Maybe unsynchronized time between the servers and workstations makes the modification times of the files unreliable. Does setting of `core.trustctime` help? (it is true by default). There is an even heavier setting: `core.ignoreStat` to ignore complete stat(2) information in change detection code.

Comment: @fork0 `core.trustctime` did the trick, if you post that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe unsynchronized time between the servers and workstations makes the modification times of the files unreliable. Does setting of `core.trustctime` help? (it is true by default). 
There is an even heavier setting: `core.ignoreStat` to ignore complete `stat(2)` information in the change detection code.