# Git refusing to merge because of changes to an unchanged file

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I'm having a git problem where I want to merge a branch into master but it's refusing to merge because it thinks I have local changes to a file. Doing status shows no changes and diffing the files produces nothing. Here's the terminal output:

```
$ git checkout ProductsAndContents
Switched to branch 'ProductsAndContents'

$ git status
# On branch ProductsAndContents
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'

$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

$ git merge ProductsAndContents
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    tests/unit/src/models/BrandTests.js
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Any help or suggestions would be most appreciated!

Comment: Have you somehow managed to put that file in the `.git/info/exclude` file or a `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Does the config options in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12167041/166732) help?

Comment: Hi Andrew, setting `core.trustctime` to false seems to have done it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Andrew Myers' comment on my initial question, I discovered setting `core.trustctime` to `false` solved the problem.

```
git config core.trustctime false
```

Something about mismatching inode change times. I'm guessing this is because the repo is sitting on a fileshare on a machine with a different file system from the one I'm using.

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're confident you won't loose any work, try the following:

```
rm tests/unit/src/models/BrandTests.js
git checkout -- tests/unit/src/models/BrandTests.js
```

That should reset any mechanism that made it think it had changes. If it doesn't work, have others that might.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Trev! I tried that but unfortunately it still gives the same error. So strange...

Comment: I also encountered this, but it appears that `git stash` would refuse to see a file as modified. I manually backed it up, checked it out, and compared the changes by hand. There's got to be a better way...

Comment: @PaulLammertsma Don't forget that a `stash` is nothing more than another commit and has its own hash. You can operate on it as you would any other commit. Which leaves many other options. I had just found the above to be the quickest.

Comment: @TrevNorris That's the weird thing; everything was committed and well. It took deleting the file, checking it out again and replying the changes for it to get sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess this is your scenario:

```
$ git checkout ProductsAndContents
Switched to branch 'ProductsAndContents'
```

Branch `ProductsAndContents` contains the file `tests/unit/src/models/BrandTests.js`, so the above `checkout` creates it and/or makes sure it's up to date with the specific commit requested.

```
$ git status
# On branch ProductsAndContents
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

You haven't made any changes, and started with a clean working directory, so this is good.

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
```

This makes sure all files contained in the latest commit on `master` are up to date in the working directory. However, it does not remove or update files that are not contained in `master`, or that are ignored. Here I assume `master` for whatever reason does not currently include the file in question.

```
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Again, you've made no modifications. The fact that the file in question is not mentioned here as an untracked file probably means it's ignored (either in `.gitignore` or in `.git/info/exclude`). `master` doesn't contain the file so it's not concerned that it exists.

```
$ git merge ProductsAndContents
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    tests/unit/src/models/BrandTests.js
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Here, your attempt to merge in the other branch wants to introduce a file that `master` currently doesn't have, which is normally fine. However, that file exists in your working directory, and `git` doesn't want to trash something that it's not sure is preserved in the repository. As suggested elsewhere, you could (assuming you know it's safe) simply remove that file and re-try the merge.

With the information you have given, I'm not 100% sure that's what you have here; you could run these two commands to check for that condition, though:

```
git ls-files master -- tests/unit/src/models/BrandTests.js
git ls-files ProductsAndContents -- tests/unit/src/models/BrandTests.js
```

If my guess is right, the first command will not show that the file exists, while the second will. Then check `.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` to see if it's being ignored (for `.gitignore`, you may need to check the version that exists on each of the two branches).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the file is in both branches and not in .gitignore or .git/info/exclude. Here's the output:

    $ git ls-files master -- tests/unit/src/models/BrandTests.js
    tests/unit/src/models/BrandTests.js
    $ git ls-files ProductsAndContents -- tests/unit/src/models/BrandTests.js
    tests/unit/src/models/BrandTests.js

Answer (score -2):

Just because each branch has nothing to commit does not mean that they are the same. I would be interested in viewing the differences between the two files using

```
git diff
```

You can revert to the revision that has been commited to the repo using

```
git checkout -- tests/unit/src/models/BrandTests.js
```

Comment: `Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.` implies uncommitted changes, not committed diffs between branches

Comment: There are really no changes to commit, and no untracked files. As I mentioned, diffing produces zero output. I'm baffled.