# How do I restore my git to the original HEAD?

Tags: git

I attempted to rollback to a previous commit and apparently I screwed up.
So I need to recover.

Fortunately I did a stash; but after applying it I got the following error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Bliss.storyboard
    Bliss2.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
    Bliss2/(3.0)DiscoveryViewController.swift
    Bliss2/(3.6)Contribute.swift
    Bliss2/(3.7)CameraContribute.swift
    Bliss2/Environment.swift
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

So I stashed again.  Here's my stashes:

```
$~/workarea/bliss/Bliss2:git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on RicBranch: e3cb317 Revert "Linked up BlissThoughts & hidden toggle for (3.6) TextView" Temp go back and see old 
stash@{1}: WIP on RicBranch: 40e664a Creation of (3.10) DiscoveryUploadViewController.
```

So I tried this and got the same error:

```
$~/workarea/bliss/Bliss2:git stash apply #1
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Bliss.storyboard
    Bliss2.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
    Bliss2/(3.0)DiscoveryViewController.swift
    Bliss2/(3.6)Contribute.swift
    Bliss2/(3.7)CameraContribute.swift
    Bliss2/Environment.swift
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
$~/workarea/bliss/Bliss2:git commit -m 'Committed garbage'
On branch RicBranch
Changes not staged for commit:
    deleted:    ../(3.6)TableViewCell.xib
    modified:   ../Bliss.storyboard
    modified:   ../Bliss2.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
    modified:   (3.0)DiscoveryViewController.swift
    modified:   (3.6)Contribute.swift
    modified:   (3.7)CameraContribute.swift
    modified:   Environment.swift

no changes added to commit
$~/workarea/bliss/Bliss2:git stash apply #1
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Bliss.storyboard
    Bliss2.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
    Bliss2/(3.0)DiscoveryViewController.swift
    Bliss2/(3.6)Contribute.swift
    Bliss2/(3.7)CameraContribute.swift
    Bliss2/Environment.swift
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
$~/workarea/bliss/Bliss2:
```

Here's a snapshot of where I'm at.  I want to rollback to 'RicBranch':

[image]

I'm trying to rollback to the 'clean' commit: the (3.10) commit.

But Git keeps saying I must do another commit/stash.

All I want to do is to rollback to my previous HEAD, before all this mess occurred.

How to I do a pop to original HEAD or apply the 2nd Stash (version 3.10)?

Comment: First - what does your `git status` show?  Also, are you trying to go back to a specific stash entry, or a commit on another branch?

Comment: This link might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164300, since it looks very related.

Comment: `git reset --hard <commit sha1>` will return you to a particular commit, unless you've already pushed your changes. (It will do that, then, too, but things get complicated on the remote side, esp. if others work with your repository too)

Answer (score 0):

Environment: Xcode 6.1

I was working within a new branch at the time I screwed up and corrupted my git.

I thought I could easily return to my original branch should I fail.  But I couldn't launch Xcode due to the corruption.

I had to go to the command line and also use gitX.  It's all a matter of fixing it...all the repository was there.

So I ended up using:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Now I'm back to where I began.

BTW: I would still like to peek at a previous commit without screwing up the app.

Comment: did you try soft reset before? Seems to me it was more a merge error, so maybe `git merge --abort` had have helped?

Answer (score 0):

For the future maybe you could use the `gil log` / or `git reflog` that gave you something like that :

```
yourHash HEAD@{0}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/dev
yourHash HEAD@{1}: commit : some commit
yourHash HEAD@{2}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/dev
...
```

Then you can do `git reset --hard yourHash` if you want to retrieve a particular state

Hope this help