# GitBucket: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge

Tags: macos, git, bitbucket

I have searched everywhere and tried various solutions but am still getting the error:
**Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge**

i have nothing to commit as status tells me the following:

```
  # On branch develop
  # Your branch is behind 'origin/develop' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  #   (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
  #
  nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

So then I do a git pull, then get the following:

```
  Updating 67020e6..6dd23de
  error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
app/filename.php
  Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
  Aborting
```

But as I have nothing to commit and if I do a git stash I get **No local changes to save**

So how can I fix the problem and download and update my local machine with my remote amends.

Bit of history incase:
I have to local machines one at home and work I have done the amends at home and pushed them and I am now trying to update my local work machine with these updates.

**EDIT UPDATE**
As I cannot answer my own question for a while I found what for me solved this answer:

on the branch I wrote:

```
    git reset --hard
```

Then the pull worked.

Comment: It may seem like a minor thing to do, but capitalizing your pronouns like "I" instead of "i" actually help a lot, because then other people don't have to go edit your question to capitalize them for you, which is something that people tend to do a lot, out of tons of generosity. You can help us help you by putting in the effort yourself first.

Comment: in a way i apologise, but when you have a form of Dyslexia i can also find it offensive, and for those whom do not have English as their first language might have problems too, i hope the amended i's have been amends to your liking

Comment: Your profile said you were from the UK, so I (erroneously) assumed that English was your first language. Regardless, you have my sincere apologies for the offense.

Comment: i'm in the UK but i am actually welsh but actually african but hey don't want to to bore you, its not problem and i take no offense

Comment: Is the origin repository on a network shared drive?  I have seen this on OSX when using a repository on a shared drive.  See [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8563207/166732).

Comment: thanks for the heads up,as i have done the reset its hard to test now but the origin is on Bitbucket both local machines i run form my sites folder not form a networked one.

Comment: Once, I was in similar situation. The problem was file mode changes (I've set `+x` locally, but on remote the files were not executable).

Comment: Please write the answer you have got below, and check it as valid, it is need in order to your question didn't show as unanswered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While looking around i tried the following that seemed to fix my issue at the time.

While on the branch i wrote.

```
   git reset --hard
```

Answer (score 2):

Had you ever previously done `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`? That could be a potential reason for your situation.

To fix, you do `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>`. Then you should be able to stash your changes and continue with the merge.

Answer (score 0):

Faced exactly the same problem. I was used to CVS before I started exploring git. I think running `git pull --rebase origin master` is the way to go for the kind of workflow that you and I use.
Refer to https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-centralized for a more detailed explanation. I definitely know the answer is somewhere in that article, but I didn't understand the article completely.